# AVAudioPlayer initialization with web URL crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I have a sound file on a server and I try to play it on device.

Using this code:

```
NSURL audioURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://..."];
NSError *error;
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:&error]
```

crashes with the error:

> Description of exception being thrown: '-[NSTaggedPointerString getCharacters:range:]: Range {0, 12} out of bounds; string length 5

The url has the length `73`.

Firstly, why is it crashing instead of populating my `error` object?

If I use this code:

```
NSURL audioURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://..."];
NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:audioURL];
NSError *error;
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:audioData error:&error]
```

it works.

Looking at the name of the methods, it looks like they do the same thing, so why isn't the first method working?
Reading the `AVAudioPlayer` init methods' documentation reveals nothing related to this problem.

Comment: what is the exact string url you are using. this may be causing the problem. try a different url?

Comment: I can't share it, but I can tell you that it's a direct url, so it doesn't goes through a server side script, and the file doesn't have an extension. And I also didn't try with other different url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you streaming your audio file?
`AVAudioPlayer` cannot stream from `URL`. You can use it with files stored on device.
If you want to stream your file from `URL` you need to use `AVPlayer`
The following code:

```
AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL: audioURL];
AVPlayer *myAVPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem: item];
```

***EDIT***

When you are going to use your AVAudioPlayer with URL you need to present your URL like this:

```
NSString *backgroundMusicPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myMusic" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *backgroundMusicURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:backgroundMusicPath];
```

Taken from [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/69369/audio-tutorial-ios-playing-audio-programatically-2014-edition)

Hope it will help

Comment: No, it downloads the file and then starts to play it.

Comment: In your first code sample you are trying to init your player with http url - it's wrong. 
You can use it, when you have your file on device. Look at my Edit

Comment: I understand, so `NSData` is actually downloading the file for me, and then passes its data to `AVAudioPlayer` in the second code sample, right?